# Zip iterables with Optional and Non Optional parameter in macro

Tags: rust, macros

For the testing part of my lexer, I came up with a simple macro that let met define the expected token type (enum) and the token literal (string):

```rust
macro_rules! token_test {
    ($($ttype:ident: $literal:literal)*) => {
        {
            vec!($($ttype,)*).iter().zip(vec!($($literal,)*).iter())
        }
    }
}
```

and then I can use it like this:

```rust
for (ttype, literal) in token_test! {
    Let: "let" Identifier: "five" Assign: "=" Int: "5" Semicolon: ";"
} {
    //...
}
```

However, this is a little bit verbose and **we don't need to specify the literal for most of the token since I have another macro that transforms an enum variant into a string (eg: Let -> "let")**.

So what I hope to do is something like:

```rust
for (ttype, literal) in token_test! {
    Let Identifier: "five" Assign Int: "5" Semicolon
} {
    //...
}
```

And if I understood properly, I can use optional parameters to match either `TYPE: LITERAL` or `TYPE`. Maybe something like:

```rust
macro_rules! token_test {
    ($($ttype:ident$(: $literal:literal)?)*) => {
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

So then my question is is there a way to build `Vector` out of this?

To be more clear:

- In the case of no literal passed, it should add the string representation of my enum (eg: Let -> "let")
- In the case of literal passed, it should add the literal directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work with the following macro (any improvement welcomed):

```rust
macro_rules! token_test {
    ($($ttype:ident$(: $literal:literal)?)*) => {
        vec!($($ttype,)*).iter().zip(vec!(
        $(
            {
                let mut literal = $ttype.as_str().unwrap();

                $(literal = $literal;)?

                literal
            }
        ),*).iter())
    }
}
```

This 'iterates' over the `literal` macro arguments and initially set the value of the `as_str` which transform a enum variant to a string. Then if the `$literal` is defined, it replaces the local literal value to that. And  finally, it returns the local literal variable.

### Improvement

```rust
macro_rules! some_or_none {
    () => { None };
    ($entity:literal) => { Some($entity) }
}

macro_rules! token_test {
    ($($ttype:ident$(: $literal:literal)?)*) => {
        vec!($($ttype,)*).iter().zip(vec!($(
            some_or_none!($($literal)?).unwrap_or($ttype.as_str().unwrap())
        ),*))
    }
}
```

Removed some unnecessary scopes, the second `.iter()`, and added `some_or_none` macro. With this way I don't need to do the `as_str` if there is a literal provided.

### Further improvement

In the above example, there are two macros that are provided. One is clearly a "private" macro, because its existence is only useful for the implementation of the other one. However, there is a small catch about how macro exports work. Unlike functions, macros cannot access a macro that was defined in the same scope, but which are not accessible from the caller. See [this playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=16025636addcddb9b08089dc5bc3fd90). This is not a problem if you don't intend to export that macro, which is possible since its only purpose is to be used in a test suite. However, you might still want to expose it publicly at a crate level, without exposing `some_or_none!`. The conventional way to do this is to integrate `some_or_none!` inside the `token_test!` macro, by prepending it with `@`:

```rust
macro_rules! token_test {
    (@some_or_none) => {
        None
    };
    (@some_or_none $entity:literal) => {
        Some($entity)
    };
    ($($ttype:ident $(: $literal:literal)?)*) => {
        vec!($($ttype,)*)
          .iter()
          .zip(vec!($(
            token_test!(@some_or_none $($literal)?)
              .unwrap_or($ttype.as_str().unwrap())
          ),*))
    };
}
```

With this version, you can safely export `test_token` without any fears as [shown in this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=25d45b1c6f1277467c05b748b7494ee5).

### Little bit more

- original idea from [steffahn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2657991/steffahn) on the Rust Forum

There is another similar way to solve that and without involving `unwrap_or`, instead of wrapping into an `Option` in the `some_or_none`, we can actually create two branches that take either `TYPE + LITERAL` or `TYPE`, like so:

```rust
macro_rules! token_test {
  (@ttype_or_literal $ttype:ident) => { $ttype.as_str().unwrap() };
  (@ttype_or_literal $ttype:ident: $literal:literal) => { $literal };
  ($($ttype:ident $(: $literal:literal)?)*) => {
    vec!($($ttype,)*)
      .iter()
      .zip(vec![$(token_test!(@ttype_or_literal $ttype$(: $literal)?)),*])
  };
}
```

### And again

As I only need an iterable than can be deconstructed as `(type, iterable)`, an array of pair is enough:

```rust
macro_rules! token_test {
  (@ttype_or_literal $ttype:ident) => { $ttype.as_str().unwrap() };
  (@ttype_or_literal $ttype:ident: $literal:literal) => { $literal };
  ($($ttype:ident $(: $literal:literal)?)*) => {
    [$(($ttype, token_test!(@ttype_or_literal $ttype$(: $literal)?))),*]
  };
}
```

so no more `vec` and no more `zip`.

### A Smart trick

[A user on the Rust forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/mixing-optional-and-non-optional-parameter-in-macro/74020/9) gave this potential trick involving ignoring the second argument if it exists. I made the solution a little bit more compact by not having two macros:

```rust
macro_rules! token_test {
  (@ignore_second $value:expr $(, $_ignored:expr)? $(,)?) => { $value };
  ($($ttype:ident $(: $literal:literal)?)*) => {
    [$(($ttype, token_test!(@ignore_second $($literal,)? $ttype.as_str().unwrap()))),*]
  };
}
```